# Oracle: extract data from MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-spatial

I have a table form which I need to extract some information. This table has an oracle spatial (MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY) column, from which I also need some data.

I started out with a simple query like this:

```
select id, field1, field2
FROM my_table;
```

After that, I was able to loop over the result to extract the data that was in the spatial column:

```
SELECT *
        FROM TABLE  (SELECT a.POSITIONMAP.sdo_ordinates
                          FROM my_table
                          WHERE ID = 18742084);
```

The POSITIONMAP.sdo_ordinates seems to usually hold 4 values, like these:

```
100050,887
407294,948
0,577464740471056
-0,816415625470689
```

I need the last 2 values. I can achieve that by changing the query into this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT rownum AS num,
            column_value AS orientatie
        FROM TABLE  (SELECT a.POSITIONMAP.sdo_ordinates
                          FROM my_table
                          WHERE ID = 18742084))
    WHERE num IN (3,4)
```

Looping over every row from my first query to extract the data from the POSITIONMAP column is of course not very performance friendly, so my query becomes slow very quickly.

I would like to retrieve all information in one query, but there are a few things that prevent me from doing so.

- Not every row in the table has data in POSITIONMAP
- Some rows do have data in POSITIONMAP, but they only contain 2 values (so not the 3rd and 4th value that I am looking for.
- I need the data in one row for every row in the table (using the previous query would result in duplicate rows

The closest I got is:

```
select
  id,
  field1, 
  field2
  t.*
  FROM my_table v,
  table (v.POSITIONMAP.sdo_ordinates) t
```

This gives my 4 rows for every row in my_table.
As soon as I try to put the rownum condition into this query, I get an error: "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Is there any way to combine what I want to do into 1 query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sdo_util.getvertices as follows:

```
select t.x,t.y
  from my_table mt
      ,table(sdo_util.getvertices(mt.positionmap)) t
 where t.id = 2
```

I'm assuming that your geometries are lines (gtype=2002) and points (gtype= 2001). If you want X,Y values for lines and empty values for point you can filter on the sdo_gtype property of the geometry object.

```
select t.x,t.y
  from my_table mt
      ,table(sdo_util.getvertices(mt.positionmap)) t
 where t.id = 2
 and mt.positionmap.sdo_gtype=2002
 union all
 select null as X,
        null as Y
 from my_table mt
 where mt.positionmap.sdo_gtype=2001
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a very useful function for my purpose! However,Some rows do have data in POSITIONMAP, but they only contain 2 values (so not the 3rd and 4th value that I am looking for, so for those rows there's no  t.id with value 2, and I lose those rows now. IS there any way to do some kind of lefgt join, so that I don't lose these rows, but get null for x and y instead?

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  select id,
         field1, 
         field2,
         t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY v.id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   my_table v,
         TABLE( v.POSITIONMAP.sdo_ordinates ) t
)
WHERE  rn IN ( 3, 4 )
```